# Selecting Xml Element Values using Linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using the enom api checking for domains with multiple tlds. The xml is returning multiple responses but using Linq I'm only finding one. I'm new to Linq but this looks right to me. Any suggestions

// xml

```
<interface-response> 
    <Domain>test.COM</Domain> 
    <RRPCode>211</RRPCode> 
    <RRPText>Domain not available</RRPText> 
    <Domain>test.NET</Domain> 
    <RRPCode>211</RRPCode> 
    <RRPText>Domain not available</RRPText> 

    <DomainCount>2</DomainCount> 
    <Command>CHECK</Command> 
    <APIType>API.NET</APIType> 
    <Language>eng</Language> 
    <ErrCount>0</ErrCount> 
    <ResponseCount>0</ResponseCount> 
    <MinPeriod>1</MinPeriod> 
    <MaxPeriod>10</MaxPeriod> 
    <Server>sjl0vwresell_t1</Server> 
    <Site>eNom</Site> 
    <IsLockable/> 
    <IsRealTimeTLD/> 
    <TimeDifference>+0.00</TimeDifference> 
    <ExecTime>0.688</ExecTime> 
    <Done>true</Done> 
    <TrackingKey>66793410-c808-4671-8039-2925ce5da78f</TrackingKey>
    <RequestDateTime>9/9/2014 6:48:07 PM</RequestDateTime> 
    <debug/> 
 </interface-response>
```

// code

```
//Run query
var recs = from x in xml.Descendants("interface-response")
  select new {
        Domain = (string) x.Element("Domain").Value,
    RRPCode = (string) x.Element("RRPCode").Value,
    RRPText = (string) x.Element("RRPText").Value
  };

try { 
  //Loop through results
  foreach (var d in recs) {
    result.AppendLine(d.Domain);
    result.AppendLine(d.RRPCode);
    result.AppendLine(d.RRPText);
   }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  result.AppendLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the entire XML file? Or rather, enough to understand the schema? Right now it looks like your root element isn't actually your root element.

Comment: your LINQ query looks fine to me. Can you post sample that reproduce the problem?

Comment: @zilabyte Please post your sample XML file.,

Comment: I think you need to consider changing structure of the XML. There should be something like `<Domains> .. </Domains>` for domains information.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The XML provided is the entire xml and what is returned from the enom api. I can not change this. I agree with Nisar that there should be a parent <Domains>. However, it is still valid XML. I can manually parse the text but I think LINQ would be the best solution.